# Replace old armored bx with new or convert to Romex in this instance?

Tags: electrical

I wanted to install another outlet box on the opposite side of this wall. This outlet is 15A and grounded via the metal box and BX cable (verified with GFCI outlet tester before disassembly).

Upon opening it up I found the wires too short to comfortably add another line out AND the white wire broke off in my hands due to age.

The entire basement of this 1960s house is armored BX cable. I don't mind replacing it with more BX because it is indeed correctly grounded.

But is there any reason NOT to switch to Romex for this last length of cable to the box pictured?

[image: box with broken wires]

[image: BX]

[image: junction box]

Comment: Where exactly are you located? People don't *usually* install conduit in residences for fun - usually they use it only when local code specifically requires it (Cook County IL, NYC, etc).

Comment: Yes, putting Romex in a conduit-land house will flag it to every home inspector as "beware, house may be full of incompetent electrical work *done without pulling a permit*, expect safety and entitlement issues and lower your offer!" Whereas, when you "do as the Romans do", nobody notices.

Comment: I sure hope there's a wire nut on those white wires under all that tape. An I hope that's not a bit of bare copper showing between the insulation and just above the tape.

Comment: Also, what does the junction box in that last picture have to do with the box in the first picture? There doesn't appear to be any BX cable coming out of that JB.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your code Romex should be fine just be sure it has the ground with it. I hope the junction box you show is not going to be covered when you finish the room. There is a possibility as you replace this piece of cable you will find more problems with other cables, be prepared for some extra work.

Comment: The junction box is in the ceiling of an adjacent room. We took down a drop ceiling in order to renovate. Won't be putting up a new one until we're satisfied with all the wiring, among other things. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: While this _is_ perfectly good and valid advice in _most_ situations, be sure, @Drew, to pay heed to the comments on your original question. It may _not_ be legal in _your_ locale, and it's possible it will raise questions in the future.